# return a scope in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I encountered the following code in a file (looks like header file) iomanip of gcc 4.5.1:

```
inline _Setbase  
setbase(int __base)  
{ return { __base }; }
```

what is the language definition of returning a scope (block)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like the new syntax for [Uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Uniform_initialization) in C++0x to me.

Comment: I think it's just normal struct initialization (should be valid C as well).

Comment: Not necessarily. If `_Setbase` is plain-old-data, it does not need C++0x. In fact that header is used even when C++0x features are not turned on, so it can't rely on them.

Comment: You can't do that in C++03, even with a POD-type, as you're not allowed to use aggregate initializer in this context. You can check for yourself: http://ideone.com/PHX5y, the commented line would work in C++03.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't returning a block. This constructs an object of type `_Setbase`, defined in the same header file as

```
struct _Setbase { int _M_base; };
```